# How can I reconnect the version history of a directory

Tags: svn

I have a number of separately imported SVN directories. I know that these are in fact versioned derivatives of each other. How can I recursively associate each file in a directory with a predecessor on a different path?

Example

t1/a/b
t1/a/c

t2/a/b
t2/a/c

I would like to inject that t1/a is the continuation of t2/a and t1/a/b is the continuation of t2/a/b

I know that this means tampering with SVNs version keeping. Still: Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Sounds like you should create a new SVN repo and then import (a copy of?) `t2`, then commit, then similarly import `t1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done very easily.  Subversion uses the ids that are assigned to the nodes as they are created to determine ancestry.

The best you could hope to do is re-create the repo, commit by commit and when you added files that are related but didn't use the `svn copy` command to do so this time.

You don't mention what you're trying to do that you care about the ancestry.  I'd guess probably merging.  We have an `--ignore-ancestry` argument to most commands that care about ancestry so that you can allow the command to work despite the fact that the files aren't related.  There are some side effects in some cases, for instance with merge you won't get merge tracking.

Comment: I was hoping to use the compare-with option for tags in Eclipse. The resources have been moved under the tags, but the structured compare requires ancestry to work. Unfortunately, the plugin us opinionated and will not allow a flag to be passed for the operation. I don't think that this is a use case that would make the subversive feature list. Sigh...